# PHP Multiple file upload to server

Tags: php, forms

This is my second question on the forum. I've exhausted all avenues of researching this on my own. I have an HTML form the will be processed with a script. In this form the user has the option to upload up to 10 images.... each image has its own entry field like this...

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The php is this...

```
$client = $_POST['company'];
$date = date("mdy");
$clientFolder = $client . $date;

mkdir('../../../uploads/' . $clientFolder . '/', 0700);
$folderPath = '../../../uploads/' . $clientFolder . '/';



if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists($folderPath . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      $folderPath . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . $folderPath . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

I can get one file to upload correctly but not more than one. I used this tutorial. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Do I need to loop through these? Or do I need unique name's and id's? Any help will be appreciated! I'm new to php.... I have to say though.. I love it!!! so far...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't browsed your full code but if you use the same name for different form elements you will lose all values except one.

There's a little exception that you'll probably want to use: adding square brackets will make PHP build an array:

```
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]">

<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file[]">
```

You can use `var_dump()` to inspect the exact structure from `$_FILES`.

Secondly, the `id` HTML attribute is supposed to hold a unique identifier. Your client-side scripting is likely to behave wrong.

Comment: This is interesting... I'm eager to learn as much as I can. I went over to the php manual to check our var_dump() but couldn't wrap my brain around this. Would you give me another hint on what to do next?

Comment: The next is step is probably the [Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to name your inputs differently (say: file1, file2 etc) then in PHP you would do something like:

```
$i = 1;
while(isset($_POST['file'.$i])){
    //do upload here
    $i++;
}
```

The reason why you get only 1 file uploaded is because you named the inputs "file" (and because you don't loop through the inputs). Change that and it should be fine.

Comment: OK so I'm trying to think this through. I would have <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />

<label for="file2">Filename:</label>
<input type="file2" name="file" id="file2" />  THEN $i = 0;
while(isset($_POST['file'.$i])){
    //do upload here  --- ???? the code that goes here starts if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") and includes whole statement???? ////
    $i++;
}

Comment: exactly, include the whole `if` statement

Comment: sorry, had a bug, `$i` should start from 1, not 0, if you are naming the inputs from file1. i've edited my post appropriately.